# Получить значения из JSON если известен только ключ

Tags: c#, json

Есть json:

```
{
        "resourceType": "Parameters",
        "parameter": [{
            "name": "return",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "ValueSet",
                "id": "f0ff2153-d170-49c0-9e8d-558ca41b9105",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1c0d1a38-e6bc-4a11-bb54-c624fc542898",
                    "lastUpdated": "2015-07-20T13:47:23.15+03:00"
                },
                "url": "urn:oid:1.2.643.2.69.1.1.1.7",
                "version": "1",
                "name": "Классификатор категорий льгот",
                "status": "active",
                "experimental": true,
                "publisher": "bla",
                "contact": [{
                    "telecom": [{
                        "system": "email",
                        "value": "support@bla.ru"
                    }]
                }],
                "compose": {
                    "import": [
                        "1.2.643.2.69.1.1.1.7_INNER"
                    ]
                },
                "expansion": {
                    "timestamp": "07/27/2017 13:19:12",
                    "parameter": [{
                        "name": "total",
                        "valueString": "69"
                    }],
                    "contains": [{
                            "code": "10",
                            "display": "Инвалиды войны"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "50",
                            "display": "Лица, награжденные знаком \"Жители блокадного Ленинграда\""
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "60",
                            "display": "Члены семей погибших инвалидов и участников ВОВ, ветеранов боевых действий"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "61",
                            "display": "Члены семей погибших в ВОВ из числа л/с групп самозащиты объектов и команд ПВО, работников госпиталей Ленинграда"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "62",
                            "display": "Члены семей погибших в/с, сотр. МВД, противопож. службы, погибших при исполнении обязанностей"
                        }...
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно получить только все значения для "display". Но предполагается что будут приходить разные json с разным форматом и соответственно нужно будет извлекать определенные значения. Известен будет только ключ.

Я попробовал сделать что-то типа такого:

```
public object ValueFromJSON(JObject json, string columnSourceName)
{            
    var v = json[columnSourceName].AsEnumerable();
}
```

Где `columnSourceName` и есть ключ с именем display, но ничего не выходит. Выкидывает в эксепшн. **Как можно получить массив значений по ключу?**

Comment: А доступно получить ответ с сервера в XML ? Потому что парсить XML легче

Comment: "**Выкидывает в эксепшн**" какой именно?представьте сообщение

Comment: @pavel1787mego к сожалению возвращается только JSON

Comment: ...всмысле вам известен код "code" и по нему нужно извлечь значение для "display" или что? Дайте пример вызовов функции и ожидаемое возвращаемое значение.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper мне известен ключ (например display или code) и по нему нужно получить значение. Т.е. нужно получить массив всех значений ключа display

Comment: Дайте примеры вызовов функции и ожидаемое возвращаемое значение.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то Вы работаете с стандартом `FHIR`. Дабы не придумывать велосипеды используйте стандартный класс модели: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/parameters.html

Comment: Возможно, проще всего будет сочинить регулярку

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы уж используете `JToken`, то почему не LINQ?

```
var root = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path));
var displayValues =
        root.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Name == "display")
            .Select(p => p.Value);
foreach (var v in displayValues)
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Это на вашем примере у меня выдаёт:

> Инвалиды войны
>   Лица, награжденные знаком "Жители блокадного Ленинграда"
>   Члены семей погибших инвалидов и участников ВОВ, ветеранов боевых действий
>   Члены семей погибших в ВОВ из числа л/с групп самозащиты объектов и команд ПВО, работников госпиталей Ленинграда
>   Члены семей погибших в/с, сотр. МВД, противопож. службы, погибших при исполнении обязанностей

---

Для вашего JSON это может быть не критично, но в общем случае такая фильтрация означает, что отфильтрованные значения могут оказаться не только примитивами наподобие строки или числа, а и чем-то более серьёзным, например, массивом или объектом. Это можно исключить при помощи дополнительного условия:

```
.Where(p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object && p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array)
```

если для вас важно получить именно простые, а не составные значения. Спасибо @sp7, отметившему эту подробность в комментариях.

Comment: Да чтоб тебя... На секунду не успел :(

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Сорри :)

Comment: @VladD в ваше решение мне кажется имеет смысл добавить проверку, на то что тип значения не является объектом или массивом, т.е. как-то так: `.Where(p => p.Name == "display" && p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object && p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array)` в противном случае, если значением ключа будет объект, то он просто будет  выведен на экран в строковом виде со всеми его свойствами. Т.е. например, если один из ключей с именем `display` в качестве значения содержал бы следующий объект  `{'name':'Вася'}`, то на экран бы вывелось `{'name':'Вася'}`.

Comment: @sp7: Ну, ТС хотел _получить_ все свойства с ключом `"display"`. Выводить их на консоль — это уже моя добавка. Согласно вопросу, ТС'у нужны _все_ подобъекты.

Comment: @VladD я понимаю, что требовалось, то что вы написали. Но можно просто дополнить ответ и обратить внимание на подобную ситуацию, возможно ТС не предусмотрел ее.

Comment: @sp7: Хм. Вы, наверное, правы, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример рекурсивного обхода всех свойств произвольного объекта:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Container c = new Container();
    PrintProperties(c);
}
public static void PrintProperties(object obj)
{
    PrintProperties(obj, 0);
}
public static void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent)
{

    if (obj == null) return;
    string indentString = new string(' ', indent);
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);

            PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Код выводит в консоль значения всех свойств заданного объекта. Вам же нужно лишь переделать вывод на сравнение по имени свойства и, если равенство верно, сохранить значение в какой-нить свой List.

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554103/recursively-get-properties-child-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: Если бы ответ был в виде XML обошлось бы в 5-7 строк...

Comment: @pavel1787mego, и что? это вы к чему?

Comment: Просто говорю свое мнение)

Comment: @pavel1787mego, нууу..)) Да, с xml получилось бы короче. Но что дано, то дано

Comment: @СергейПолушин насколько я понял вопрос, поиск должен был осуществляться в `JSON` файле, про получение списка всех свойств объекта вопрос не шел или я не прав?

Comment: @sp7, судя по вопросу автор научился получать из файла объект JObject. Далее пройдемся по всем свойствам этого объекта и получим нужные нам значения. В этом заключалось решение. Я думал, очевидно..

Comment: @СергейПолушин а каким образом пересекаются свойства объекта `JObject`  и `JSON` данные, которые он представляет?

Comment: @sp7, боже.. Я уверен, что человек в состоянии понять, что строка в формате json десериализуется в объект..

Comment: @Сергей Полушин человек написал, что формат `JSON` будет разным, следовательно преобразовать его в объектный вид не всегда представляется возможным.

Comment: @sp7, ну почему же? Object o = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json); поможет

Comment: @СергейПолушин можно было этот вариант и опубликовать, только написали бы еще к нему метод, который рекурсивно обходит возвращенный методом `DeserializeObject` объект типа `Dictionary<string, object>` в поиске всех нужных ключей и их значений.